# Http Request&Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, struts-1

I have to make a request to a pipl.com ( http://apis.pipl.com//search/v2/json/?email=maryuca_alias%40yahoo.com&person_mode=all&exact_name=0&no_sponsored=0&key=myKey) in oder to get some information about a person.The response of this request is a json object.
I am not able to do this with a ajax/jquery/jsonp call because their server does not support this types of call.
  Is there a way to process the response on server side (I use Struts 1) or client side?

If you have a solution ,please answer this question.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getJSONP(url, success) {
var ud = '_' + +new Date,
script = document.createElement('script'),
head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] 
|| document.documentElement;
window[ud] = function(data) {
head.removeChild(script);
alert(data);
success && success(data);
};
script.src = url.replace('callback=?', 'callback=' + ud);
head.appendChild(script);
}
getJSONP('http://apis.pipl.com//search/v2/json/?email=maryuca_alias
%40yahoo.com&person_mode=all&exact_name=0&no_sponsored=0
&key=key&callback=?', function(data){
console.log(data);
});     
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) to make the request from Java, probably in a service called by the action class. That response can be processed by either Java or JavaScript, depending on your needs.

Comment: I will try this.It seems like the most suitable.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, it looks like u make a valid cross site request, but u get header different than expected or data not  JSON  formated?

if its just headers of response are not proper u can always parse data on client side. best way to specify problems would be pasting headers of request, response and code

Comment: It's not a valid cross site request.With a classic ajax call I get the error origin not allowed.So I tried with jsonp call but pipl.com does not support this format.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

yea, i ve read their documentations - qiute poor.

what i can recommaned u is to try using jsonp/ajax from jquery.

or a bit more trciky thing but will work 100% - call with ajax script on our server that simply get page content with cURL or any other http request library.